# (Socket.IO) how to add class to current user's username in userlist?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Basically I'm working on a chat room application and I'm using forEach to list all of the users in the room, how would I add a class to only the current user's username?

Code

```
socket.on('updateUserList', function(users) {
  var ul = $('<ul class="ul-unstyled"></ul>');

  users.forEach(function(user) {
    ul.append($('<li class="userlist__item"></li>').text(user));

    if(users.length <= 1) {
      $('#counter').text(users.length + " Member");
    } else {
      $('#counter').text(users.length + " Members");
    }
  });
  $('#users').html(ul);
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a id or a unique identifier to the current username (e.g. id)

```
    var id = myid; //(e.g. current user id)
    socket.on('updateUserList', function(users) {
      var ul = $('<ul class="ul-unstyled"></ul>');

      users.forEach(function(user) {
        //If current user is equal to current id
        if(user.id == id){
         ul.append($('<li class="userlist__item YOUR_CURRENT_USERNAME CLASS"></li>').text(user));
        } else {
         ul.append($('<li class="userlist__item"></li>').text(user));
        }
        if(users.length <= 1) {
          $('#counter').text(users.length + " Member");
        } else {
          $('#counter').text(users.length + " Members");
        }
      });
      $('#users').html(ul);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but when I do this, it simply adds class to every <li> if condition is met, rather than actual <li> that has the current user in.

Comment: But you are asking on "How to add a class to current user's username in userlist". Are you talking about the class attribute?

Comment: I am asking to add a class only to the current user's username within the userlist, no other items.

Comment: Is the current username inside the <li> tag?